# Citrix XenApp connection

Tags: c#, vpn, citrix, xenapp

I need to implement citrix connection through my own application. The situation is such that currently connects via a web browser with name and password and after completing Citrix XenApp send me sms code that I enter into the browser will be redirected to page with the applications that can run.

I suppose that if I identify in this way , it will connect to XenApp act as a VPN network and will have access to applications (the internal corporate web) over the PC .

Needed to process the data programmatically from a web application that I can run after connecting to XenApp , but if I make web request from my application to specify URL, so the URL does not exist.

I found on the Citrix Web site that exists PowerShell SDK, but unfortunately I could not find out how and whether it is even possible to connect this way.

The point is that the application is a classic WinForms programming in . NET 4.0. After connecting to the Citrix should download from fixed URL address the file and save it to the disk. After processing by user (in application too) via a web service that file again to send it back.

Does anyone know how I can achieve that with the application to connect to XenApp and had access to internal web applications ?

Thank you so much for your advice , or assistance with directions, which way to go.

Comment: So, basicaly, you have a local app, which should open a citrix session via ICA with remote server, download a file (accessible only within citrix farm), process it (inside of this local application) and send it back within the citrix session? Would it be easier to embed this app in citrix environment? Or even, write an additional simple citrix published app / web app, which would be responsible for downloading a file and send it back from your local disk after you finished processing it?

Comment: If the only way to send back this file, is using this local application (and it's closed source), then it can be difficult. I've never heard of VPN-like tunnel for XenApp servers and clients. There are some 3rd party solutions though, but then, why do you need XenApp? Only to get access to your remote network?

Comment: The problem is complicated because it exactly describe it would be a small novel :-).

In any case, I found the API directly from Citrix XenApp and some guidance. I also found the library that contains the Citrix client (or plug-in) that make this possible, but I can not find a reasonable documentation where this explains how to work effectively with it.